# moviepy ruining video after combining them

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, moviepy

I'm trying to make a program that downloads videos from TikTok and combines all the separate videos into one .mp4 file and moves the final video to a folder on my desktop. I've been able to make it download all the videos and when I watch the separate videos they play fine however when I combine the videos some of the videos are messed up and look like this but the audio is fine.[image: video looks like this]

```
#slecting all .mp4 files
    video_files = glob.iglob("*.mp4")

    print(video_files)
    clips = []

    for clip in video_files:  # For each mp4 file name
        clips.append(VideoFileClip(clip))  # Store them as a VideoFileClip and add to the clips list

    today = date.today()

    final = concatenate_videoclips(clips)  # Concatenate the VideoFileClips
    final.write_videofile(f"{today}.mp4", codec="libx264")


#moving completed video to folder on desktop
    shutil.move(f'{today}.mp4', '/Users/jacobmarrandio/Desktop/done_videos/')
```

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to ensure that all of your videos are of the same size before concatenating. Or, you could modify the smaller clips to have a black margin by filling up space by making this change:

```
final = concatenate_videoclips(clips, method='compose')
```